# C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type with string and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, hash, unordered-map

I am trying to implement an std::unordered_map with std::string as the key and std::unique_ptr as the value. However, when I try to compile, I get the error:

`error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.`

Looking around at different questions, I know that C++11 does indeed include a std::hash < std::string >, and I can see no reason why this error would be thrown. I've tried to implement my own hashing function, like the one seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595804/c-hash-function-for-string-in-unordered-map/15595840#15595840), but it is still throwing the same error. I have also tried using `__declspec(dllexport)` and making the copy constructor and assignment operator for the containing class private, as it is suggested in some threads to make unique_ptr work, but to no avail.

Here is the code for the offending class:

```
#ifndef __TEXTURE_MAP_H__
#define __TEXTURE_MAP_H__

#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

//__declspec for std::unique_ptr compat.
class /*__declspec(dllexport)*/ TextureMap : virtual public IconRegister
{
private:
    uint32 _textureId;
    std::unordered_map<const std::string, std::unique_ptr<AtlasTexture> > _registeredIcons;
    std::unordered_map<const char*, AtlasTexture*> _uploadedIcons;
    std::vector<AtlasTexture*> _animatedIcons;

public:
    TextureMap();
    ~TextureMap();

    uint32 getTextureId();

    void loadTextureAtlas();

    /* override */ IIcon& registerIcon(const char*);
    void registerIcons();

private:
    TextureMap(const TextureMap& other) { }
    TextureMap& operator= (const TextureMap& other) { return *this; };
};

#endif
```

I cannot find any reason this should not be working, and I've tried pretty much every other solution I could find when I searched for the problem.

I am using MSVC 2012.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Addition of the AtlasTexture class: [header](http://pastebin.com/1jAu9jgf) and [implementation](http://pastebin.com/jewHvcxe)

EDIT: My implementation of the move and move assignment: [here](http://pastebin.com/snqSHTUh).

Comment: Your `_registeredIcons` key shouldn't be `const` - just plain old `std::string` (`hash` is specialised for `string` not `const string`).  Also, `std::hash(const char*)` will hash the pointer's address, not the pointed-to text.... is that really what you want?

Comment: Well, the problem is without the const in front of the string, I start getting a new error: " error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' "

Comment: I think that's because `unique_ptr<>` isn't a valid type to map to... per 23.2.5.10 "key_type and mapped_type are sometimes
required to be CopyAssignable" - `unique_ptr` is not CopyAssignable.  You could use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: If you really think it is a problem with hashing, try something simpler, such as `unordered_map<string, int>`. Reomve all other confounding factors (the `const`, the `unique_ptr`).

Comment: I have seen examples of code which use unique_ptr as map values. I could change the classes a bit to use shared_ptr, but I really would prefer to avoid that if possible. Are you absolutely sure that this cannot be done?

Comment: What's the line of code reporting the new error?

Comment: @TonyD I think that *sometimes* is very important there, I think it means certain member functions may required `mapped_type` to be CopyAssignable, but not all. Certainly works in [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f3a127c1a12358e) trivial use case.

Comment: IIRC, There's a bug in MSVC's implementation that forbids use of `unique_ptr` as a `value_type`.

Comment: @Praetorian: certainly... I think it's only if you use an initialiser list... that's why I asked to see the line of code provoking the error.  GCC used to have a bug with unique_ptr though, interesting that Casey suspects MSVC too.

Comment: Actually, I cannot find a specific line that is generating this error. However, part of the error output is : "This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)'"

Comment: @TonyD Yeah, an initializer list would definitely not work because that only allows `const` access to its members. I think VALOD9 has the correct answer below. sm81095: Try implementing move constructor and move assignment operator for `AtlasTexture`.

Comment: I withdraw my accusation: [`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>>` seems to be usable in VS2013.](http://rextester.com/XKTD44767).

Comment: @sm81095 The copy constructor of pair complaining indicates that the problem is probably with how you are inserting `unique_ptr`s into the map. Can you show us that part of the code? (I assume `registerIcon`/`registerIcons`?)

Comment: This is the most recent implementation that I came across: `_registeredIcons.insert(std::move(std::make_pair(path, std::unique_ptr<AtlasTexture>(obj))));`, where path is a `const char*` and `obj` is an AtlasTexture pointer created only a few lines above.

Comment: @sm81095 That's the copy: it's converting the result of `make_pair` - `std::pair<const char*,std::unique_ptr<AtlasTexture>>` - to the value_type of the map `std::pair<const std::string,std::unique_ptr<AtlasTexture>>`. I suggest using `emplace` instead of `insert`. (Also, it's pointless to `std::move` the result of a function which is already an rvalue).

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/1e7XhXJT) is the entire `registerIcons()` function.

Comment: @Casey then how do I go about properly inserting the unique_ptr?

Comment: @sm81095 The easy way is to use [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace). The hard way is to use `insert(std::pair<const std::string,std::unique_ptr<AtlasTexture>>(path,std::unique_ptr<AtlasTexture>(obj)))`. Specifically, `_registeredIcons.emplace(path, std::unique_ptr<AtlasTexture>(obj));`

Comment: I replaced the code with the stuff from above, however I am still getting the same issue. The error consistently contains `This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)'`. Could `for (auto pair : _registeredIcons)` be causing this?

Comment: @sm81095: yes, by default `auto` is a copy; you could specify either `auto&` or `auto const&` depending on whether the reference can be `const` or not.

Comment: Ok, I can actually compile it now any it mostly seems to work (unrelated crash keeps occuring). It seems that it was a combination of changing the `.insert()` to `.emplace` and changing `auto` to `auto&`. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: @sm81095 Please create an answer and answer yourself, also marked it as correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was with how I was placing the `std::unique_ptr`s into the map. The best way to place it in is to use `map::emplace()` instead of `map::insert()`. This is becasue there is no copy constructor for `std::unique_ptr` and emplace moves the object instead of copies it. Thanks to @Casey for this answer.

My other issue was using the new `auto` type in order to get the pairs from the map. Again, becasue the `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, which happens when `auto` gets changed to `std::pair`, this was throwing a compiler error. The nice easy fix for this was to use `auto&` instead of `auto`. Thanks to @MatthieuM. for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to implement all compile generated methods af AtlasTexture?

Comment: Dude, stop with the comments posing as answers. It's very unlikely this has something to do with `AtlasTexture`. That error he posted in the comments above most likely means he's trying to copy construct/copy assign a `unique_ptr` somewhere.

Comment: I apologize for the earlier comment. [You may have hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870359/visual-c-2010-unordered-map-and-move-constructor) the nail on the head; the problem very well could be that the OP hasn't implemented a move constructor for `AtlasTexture`, and MSVC doesn't generate move constructors implicitly.

Comment: I added a link to my implementation of the move and move assignments. I am not familiar with these so I basically just implemented what I think the standard copy constructor does.